# argparse define fraction as default parameter

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I want to pass a fraction in the shell. Underneath is the Python code.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('parser')
parser.add_argument('--eps', type=float, default=1./2., help='epsilon')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.eps)
```

Then, I start the python script:

```bash
python main.py --eps 1./2.
```

and I get this error:

```bash
 error: argument --eps: invalid float value: '1./2.`
```

How to pass `1./2.`?  To pass `0.5` is not an answer because it should also work for `200/3200`.

Comment: Which shell? `python main.py --eps "$((1./2.))"` works for me in zsh, but not bash

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I use bash a solution for bash would fine

Comment: This isn't a problem with the `default`, but with the `type` function.  `float('200/300')` gives the error.  Either use a shell that converts the string to float, or define a `type` function  that can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't handle floating arithmetic, so instead you need an external tool like `bc(1)` (which is usually bundled with bash):

```
python main.py --eps $(bc <<< "scale=5; 1./2.")
```

where `scale` is the number of digits after the decimal point, the default being zero.

On many shells (including some versions of `bash`), `python main.py --eps "$((1./2.))"` would work.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/398544)